# Word for "ability to hide complexity"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for *ability to hide complexity*  or *ability to hide details*?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context?  In programming, we'd probably say "encapsulate," but if you're talking about a person, that wouldn't work.

Comment: Facade pattern ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern ), if you're computer guy :)

Comment: Half the time, when seeing the "single-word-requests" tag I wonder if people are yearning for English to be more like German (or Welsh?) and to allow complexityhidingabilty.

Answer (score 16):

"Abstraction"

> the act of considering something as a general quality or characteristic, apart from concrete realities, specific objects, or actual instances.

Answer (score 9):

You might consider *facile*:

> **facile** |ˈfasəl|
>   *adjective*
>   1 (esp. of a theory or argument) appearing neat and comprehensive only by ignoring the true complexities of an issue; superficial. [NOAD]

Answer (score 1):

In certain contexts you might use [this](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/legerdemain?region=us):

> **legerdemain** /ˌlejərdəˈmān, ˈlejərdəˌmān, /
>    noun
>   skillful use of one's hands when
>   performing conjuring tricks.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.thefreedictionary.com/facade

> Facade: An artificial or deceptive front

Answer (score 1):

glib:

*He was glib in his explanations, despite a deep understanding of the issues.*

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly a synonym, but how about "vulgarize"? It is more "make comprehensible to non-experts", but that might suit you, depending on the context.

Comment: I'd use *popularize* in the meaning *to present in generally understandable or interesting form*. *Vulgarize* sounds a bit negative to me.

Answer (score -1):

Edited:

How about:

> Disguise
>   that which disguises; something that serves or is intended for concealment of identity, character, or quality;

Comment: The OP didn't specify that the hiding of complexity was dishonest.

Answer (score -1):

There's always *liar,* telling a lie is a great way to cover up underlying complexity.

Comment: While telling a lie may be a way to cover up complexity "liar" is not a word that means "able to hide complexity".

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can try [obfuscate](http://www.wordnik.com/words/obfuscate)

> (computing) To alter code while
>   preserving its behavior but conceal
>   its structure and intent. *We need to
>   obfuscate these classes before we ship
>   the final release.*

Comment: I think the meaning of "obfuscate" is closer to "ability to hide simplicity"

Comment: @Lie if you can obfuscate simplicity, I think you can also obfuscate complexity ;)

Comment: @pageman: I think you're getting it wrong; "obfuscate" by itself, means taking something which is simple and make it more complex or appear more complex than it actually is. Obfuscation may be used to conceal data/information, but there are methods of concealing information that are not obfuscation. You can't `obfuscate simplicity` nor `obfuscate complexity`, they does not make sense.

Comment: @Lie TRUE: Obfuscation maybe used to conceal data/information. TRUE: There are methods of concealing info that are not obfuscation. How do you connect that to YOUR idea that you CAN'T obfuscate simplicty NOR obfuscate complexity? If I use very idiomatic code - it would be SIMPLE to me and anybody well-versed in that programming language. That is "obfuscating simplicity". If I converts something "naturally" recursive by using a loop that is "obfuscating complexity". Take your pick.

Comment: @pageman: obfuscating is not a synonym of hiding/concealing. obfuscating is a synonym of hiding simplicity. obfuscating complexity is a weird expression trying to say `hiding simplicity complexity`, which doesn't make sense even if you make it grammatical. Without any additional adjectives,  `obfuscated something` already carries the connotation of being more complex than `something` itself; while `obfuscate complexity` is merely redundant `obfuscate simplicity` is bizzare. See, http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obfuscate to get a sense of the word.

Comment: @Lie you just contradicted yourself. See your first comment. If there was a Likert scale from 0 to 9 I don't think you thought it was at 0 and must be thinking from 6 to 7.

Comment: @pageman: how do I contradict myself? I said '"obfuscate" is closer to "ability to hide simplicity"' and then I said 'obfuscating is a synonym of hiding simplicity'? I think you're totally confused of the meaning of the word.

Comment: @Lie if you grade something on a scale and it's from zero to n and it's not "n" then you cannot use the boolean NOT, can't you? ;) keep commenting - it just builds my case of who's confused ;)

Comment: @pageman: I give up trying to convince you. 3 people gave me thumbs up for my original comments, and there are two thumbs up on two my other comments, meanwhile none on any of yours; that means there are at least 3 people who agreed with me, and you know what, you are correct, we are all confused, all four of us are wrong.

Comment: @Lie the answer "lies" (maybe some pun intended) somewhere in between that scale that you gave - just because your 3 of your friends upvoted you doesn't mean anything, doesn't it? ;)

Answer (score -3):

*[simplify](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/simplify)*

> make (something) simpler or easier to do or understand.
>
> *ODO*

Comment: Hi Ron, welcome to ELU!  Can you provide a link to where you found this definition?  See [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5196/106801) for how to cite sources.  Thanks!