# Alternative to “façade”

Tags: word-choice

In software development, I’m using the so-called “Façade Pattern” to hide the complexity of a workflow via abstraction and encapsulation. I’m naming my classes using a *“_Façade”* suffix, so like *Customer_Façade*, *Filesystem_Façade*, and such.

I’d like a better word to use in my naming convention. What is an alternative to *façade*?

I've seen the question [Word for "ability to hide complexity"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29022/word-for-ability-to-hide-complexity), but it does not provide an acceptable answer.

**After thought**: I’m actually wondering whether I should even try to find a generalized word from the English language, or whether I should instead try to find a word from the specific domain (software development), considering that these will have different meanings depending on context — for example, *Profile*.

Comment: Why not *abstraction* or *encapsulation* as you have suggested?

Comment: Not abstraction because the meaning would be ambiguous with the platform since it already has a definition of abstract classes. Encapsulation is pretty long, but it doesn't seem to fit. 'RegistrationEncapsulation' vs 'RegistrationFacade'

Comment: Why not use *facade*?  It's a widely accepted term in OOP.

Comment: As a potentially dumb question/thought, does your code lose any sense if you don't tag things as a facade?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. It will lose sense if it isn't tagged and that's why I'm looking for a good name for the convention.

Comment: I'd be reluctant to change the word, even if you find a better alternative. To anyone familiar with established design patterns, the "_Facade" suffix will make it instantly clear that the class was formed using that pattern. By changing the name, you run the risk of losing that association. (It might read better today, but the maintainers down the road might begrudge you, particularly if you use the "*_PatternName*" suffix for other established patterns interspersed throughout your system.) Just a thought.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is off-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems more like a programming question than an English-language one, but 
here’s my answer anyway:

I question whether you need a suffix for these classes. Unless you have both `Customer` and `CustomerFacade` classes, you should just call your single class a `Customer`. If you do need the second class to hide certain features then perhaps a suffix like `Worker` or `Interface` would be appropriate, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: +1 I agree with you. I was thinking of 'Service' instead. I do need a suffix to differentiate the two.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but for a reason not stated: using these kinds of identifiers strongly suggests that the developer is thinking in terms of the *representation* rather than the *thing being represented*.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is arising from your getting stuck with 'hiding complexity.' I'd suggest using a simpler, familiar term and assigning it the relevant meaning only for the context. Such as **Profile**: generally, the real 'face' of something. However, we assign it the special meaning of a simpler 'public face' of what is otherwise a complex thing for our context.

Comment: viz. CustomerProfile; FileSystemProfile; ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for *abstraction*.

Comment: Be careful with "abstraction" since this has a meaning in object-oriented programming languages which may not be appropriate here. An abstract class can never be instantiated.

Comment: See my comment on my question about using abstraction. It's ambiguous in this context.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that... Sorry.